# Where can I find a chart or data comparing CPU speed to memory speed?

Tags: cpu, speed

If you look at [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20070202193956/http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds5-3/pmgap.html), there is a chart of memory speed versus CPU speed from 1980 - 2000. I need to use a similar chart in a research paper, and I need a good set of data from a reputable source to use for the chart.

[image]

Does anyone know where I could find this?

Comment: Took the liberty to add the chart you referred to

Comment: Image is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is looking up the frequencies of the main processor/memory types ([like Pentium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium)) on Wikipedia, since they tend to give you some nice tables with an overview of their specs.

In the case of Pentium you get a very broad range (in time) of frequencies, which is probably what your after.

For memory, someone else will have to suggest a type or brand though you could look for things like DDR memory etc.

Downside: you'll have to create a graph like this yourself, though with Excel, that shouldn't be too hard. And in case you miss some years, just interpolate ;-) Moore's Law will keep you safe!

Comment: The problem with just looking at frequencies is that it doesn't take other factors of the architecture into account. If you took a 3GHz P4 and a single core of a 3GHz Core 2 Duo, the C2D will win hands down because of the refined architecture behind it, even if you manually force the busses and all other components to the same speed.

Comment: Totally true, but I don't know of a database of benchmarks that go back 15-20 years. You can't exactly compare Win95 performance with Win7...

Comment: Agreed, that is a problem. The OP may have to go digging through old white papers and release docs for a completely accurate comparison. The problem with those is that a lot of the info in there isn't real world performance. It's kind of a catch 22